# Swift Difference Between Literal And String Newline Characters

Tags: swift, xml

I have a Swift application for iOS where inherit from XMLParser to parse an XML file.  In one section I grab an attribute which may contain `\n` characters.  These strings are used as button titles later.

Sample XML:

```
<button title="TitleLine1\nTitleLine2"/>
```

And in my `didStartElement()` function:

```
var buttonTitle : String = attributeDict["title"]
```

This grabs the title just as I would expect, however later when I create the button and apply the title, the newline character is simply printed right in line on the button instead of making the button title two lines.

I expect the button to look like this:

```
TitleLine1
TitleLine2
```

But it ends up being:

```
TitleLine1\nTitleLine2
```

If I forget the XML parsing altogether and simply hard code the button title with a literal string like this, the newline works:

```
button.setTitle("TitleLine1\nTitleLine2", for: .normal)
```

However setting it with my variable results in the newline being printed in line:

```
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
```

Is there some different way the XMLParser handles strings?  I notice the same behavior if I simply do a `print()` with the XML parsed string vs a literal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `\n` in a Swift string literal is converted to an actual newline character during compilation.

The character `\` followed by the character `n` in some piece of text obtained at runtime has no special meaning of any kind.

You have a few choices. When you parse the XML, you can process all strings and replace occurrences of the character sequence `\n` with an actual newline character:

```
let str = someXMLValue.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```

Another option is to change your XML structure to use an element for the title instead of an attribute. Then you can put a real newline in the title:

```
<button>
    <title>TitleLine1
TitleLine2</title>
</button>
```

Then your Swift code doesn't need to do anything special to deal with newlines.